# Getting specific values from attribute

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to get a specific value from an element that has on omouseover attribute. I need the value that comes after the text "uran voitto%" which in this case is 7,85 but I couldn't figure out how to do that because everything is "inside" the onmouseover attribute.
The site in question is https://ravit.is.fi/paivanravit/?lahto=147497
and the element is

```
<td id="ohjastaja_info_11" style="cursor: pointer;" class="infolink" onmouseover="return overlib('<table bgcolor=#CCCCCC cellspacing=1 width=250><tr bgcolor=#FFFFFF><td align=right width=30><strong>Vuosi</strong></td><td align=right width=30><strong>Startit</strong></td><td align=right width=30><strong>Voitot</strong></td><td align=right width=30><strong>2.&nbsp;sijat</strong></td><td align=right width=30><strong>3.&nbsp;sijat</strong></td></tr><tr  bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=right><td align=right width=30><strong>18:</strong></td><td align=right width=30>801</td><td align=right width=30>50</td><td align=right width=30>81</td><td align=right width=30>100</td></tr><tr  bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=right><td align=right width=30><strong>17:</strong></td><td align=right width=30>1164</td><td align=right width=30>83</td><td align=right width=30>112</td><td align=right width=30>108</td></tr><tr  bgcolor=#FFFFFF align=right><td align=right width=30><strong>Yht:</strong></td><td align=right width=30>18734</td><td align=right width=30>1470</td><td align=right width=30>1651</td><td align=right width=30>1711</td></tr></table>',  CAPTION, 'Jarmo&nbsp;Saarela&nbsp; - &nbsp; uran voitto% 7,85', BGCOLOR, '#004d80', FGCOLOR, '#EAEAEA',  CAPCOLOR, '#FFFFFF', WIDTH, 250)" onmouseout="nd()">
           J&nbsp;Saarela</td>
```

Hopefully I was specific enough.

Comment: get the value for onmouseover and then the substring between "uran voitto%" and the closing `'`

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup can't do this alone. It's not able to parse HTML from JavaScript fragment, but you can use regular expression to get this single value.

```
    String onmouseover = doc.select("td#ohjastaja_info_11").attr("onmouseover");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("uran voitto% ([\\d,]+)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(onmouseover);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: I was able to use substringBefore() and substringAfter() from the full onmouseover attribute to get just the info I needed.